# translate 'stretcher bars' to German

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Translate 'stretcher bars' to German. Example:

> As an artist I need stretcher bars to prepare a new canvas for making a painting. I also need bars in between the stretcher frame to stabilize the stretcher.

Was ist das auf deutsch?

Comment: To close voters: not all dictionaries give the contextual correct translation. My favorite dictionary claims that it is a [Schieberstange](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/stretcher%20bars). We should not close all questions that may get an answer by consulting a single dictionary, e.g. dict.cc (still there we will get no idea if the answer fits the context).

Answer (score 2):

The framework artists stretch their canvas on ("stretcher-frame") is

> der Keilrahmen

The parts you use to construct this ("stretcher-bars") are

> die Keilrahmenleiste (pl. Keilrahmenleisten)

A stabilizing bar would be

> eine Keilrahmenstrebe

Answer (score -1):

Ich schlage vor (unbelastet von tieferem Fachwissen, denn die Keilrahmen, mit denen ich früher mal arbeitete, waren klein und brauchten keine Versteifungen):

> Keilrahmenspanner
>
> Spannlatten
>
> Streben

(Kommentator PiedPiper oben erwähnte noch "Keilrahmenleiste". Ob das üblich ist, weiß ich nicht. Ich finde es leicht irreführend. Währe die "Keilrahmenleiste" nicht die Leiste, die den eigentlichen Rahmen bildet?)

Answer (score -1):

The words I was looking for auf Deutsch: Keilrahmen und Zwischenstücke.